# Xcode(version 13.3.1) doesn’t support iOS 15.6

Tags: ios, xcode12, xcode13.3.1

I updated my iPhone to iOS 15.6 yesterday and I wanted to build in Xcode (version 13.3.1). But in Xcode it is showing 'iPhone (unsupported OS version)'.
The Xcode release notes are not showing this version supports.
https://xcodereleases.com

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. On any Device Support Websites, you can only see 15.5 & 16.0. 15.6 it's meant to be just for some bug fixes but it looks like they didn't build a device support, at least not yet for this realease. If you get xcode 14 beta, is the same: nothing in between 15.5 & 16.0. If I find a Device Support will let you know. Please post something if you found already!

Comment: It might be a good idea to upgrade to ios 16 where you do have Device Support. But it is a beta version so be cautious!

Comment: This is bad advice. Many people have device that not get iOS 16

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can debug **iOS(15.6)** by using **Xcode 13.4.1**, which is not showing in release notes **Xcode 13.4.1**.

Comment: I could not debug until I removed and reconnected the iPhone using iOS 15.6.

Comment: This worked for me after restarting both my Mac and iPhone.

Answer (score 37):

Alternative option which works for Xcode 13.2.1:

1. Close Xcode.
2. Download 15.5 from here https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport/blob/master/15.5.zip
3. Unzip and **rename** it to 15.6
4. Move 15.6 folder to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`
5. (Optional for WatchOS)- If you've Apple Watch paired with your iPhone download the latest watchOS version from here https://github.com/filsv/watchOSDeviceSupport and move file to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`

Comment: This works for Xcode (version 13.3.1) too.

Comment: This worked for me as well for Xcode 13.3.1

Comment: Did not work on 13.4.1 xcode with iPhone 12 pro 15.6

Comment: Thanks man it started working I almost made my mind to update Xcode.

Comment: Worked for me in Xcode 13.4.1

Comment: Xcode is such a joke

Comment: Worked for me in Xcode 13.4.1 with iPhone 11 pro max 15.6

Comment: Worked Xcode 13.2 iphone x

Comment: I pulled those files from Xcode 14.2 which didn't want to launch, and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

tested, iOS 15.6 phone is running Xcode 13.4.1

The iOS & iPadOS 15.5 SDK provides support to develop apps for iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch devices running iOS & iPadOS 15.6. The SDK comes bundled with Xcode 13.4.1, available from the Mac App Store. For information on the compatibility requirements for Xcode 13.4.1.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-15_6-release-notes

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, in my case it was due to a paired Apple Watch. I solved it by deleting the device from Xcode and adding it again, while ensuring that the paired Apple Watch was unlocked and being worn (I had to tap the "Trust" button on the watch). This worked with iOS 15.6 on Xcode 13.4.1

Attempting to add the device while the watch was locked and on the dock would fail with this message. YMMV.

Comment: Did not have a paired Apple Watch, but removing and adding the iPhone helped to solve it anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Same as @miletliyusuf, but just navigate to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/` and duplicate the 15.5 folder and rename to 15.6, works instantly